# Canvas clears unprogrammed rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

*I am just beginning to learn javascript and canvas, so if it is some simple mistake I'm very sorry, but right now I have no idea what could it be.*

So, I am writing a [**2d train simulator**](https://c9.io/sergeypetushkov/trains/workspace/trains.html) and while trying to implement SAT I made a radar, that shows position of `train_1` and `train_2` relative to the `train_0` just to see, how projecting corners of the train_n box to the other train SoA works.

This function draws radar background:

```
function drawRadar() {
    rContext.rect(-rWidth/2*c,-rWidth/2*c,rWidth*c,rWidth*c);
    rContext.fill();

    rContext.beginPath();
    rContext.moveTo(-rWidth/2*c,0);
    rContext.lineTo(rWidth*c,0);
    rContext.moveTo(0,-rWidth/2*c);
    rContext.lineTo(0,rWidth*c);
    rContext.stroke();
}
```

And this draws train boxes and animates all the stuff:

```
function animateRadar(){

    rContext.clearRect(-rWidth/2*c,-rWidth/2*c,rWidth*c,rWidth*c);
    drawRadar();

    if (trainCount!=null){

        if (poehavshiy) rContext.rotate(window["train_"+N].angle * toRad);

        for (var i=0;i<trainCount;i++){
            var box = window["train_"+i].box();

            var p1,p2,p3,p4;

            p1=XYtoBoxCoordinates(window["train_"+N],box[0][0],box[0][1]);
            p2=XYtoBoxCoordinates(window["train_"+N],box[1][0],box[1][1]);
            p3=XYtoBoxCoordinates(window["train_"+N],box[2][0],box[2][1]);
            p4=XYtoBoxCoordinates(window["train_"+N],box[3][0],box[3][1]);


            rContext.beginPath();
            rContext.moveTo(p1[0],p1[1]);
            rContext.lineTo(p2[0],p2[1]);
            rContext.lineTo(p3[0],p3[1]);
            rContext.lineTo(p4[0],p4[1]);
            rContext.lineTo(p1[0],p1[1]);
            rContext.stroke();
        }
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animateRadar);
}
```

What I can't understand is why I'm getting this white space in one of the trains

[image]

Please, help!

Comment: Also remember to use `beginPath()` for rectangles as they are added to the current path as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing something wrong with the transformations. I tried this code inside `drawRadar()` and it removes the "white" space:

```
rContext.save();
rContext.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
rContext.fillRect(0, 0, radar.width, radar.height);
rContext.restore();
```

This resets the transform to identity and fills the whole canvas with black. Note that the white space that you get is actually the background of the website, because you are using `clearRect`, which clears to transparent color.

Also, this removes the white space but this is not an actual solution. You have to fix whatever you are doing wrong with the transformations.

Comment: thank you, that helped. Indeed, I'm doing some transforms on the canvas. Could you please look what could cause the problem? Here is the code from sys.js, that initiates before all the other stuff:`rContext.translate(rWidth/2,rWidth/2);
rContext.rotate(180 * toRad);
rContext.scale(-1/c,1/c);`

Comment: the best would probably be applying the initial transformation inside the loop after clearing with black and drawing the radar, that way you can use (0,0),(width,height) coords when clearing and drawing the radar, would need save/restore aswell